# Interpreting Figure 1 in the "On Lattices, Learning with Errors, Random Linear Codes, and Cryptography"

Tags: lwe

I'm reading ["On Lattices, Learning with Errors, Random Linear Codes, and Cryptography"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1060603) by O. Regev.

I'm having trouble with understanding graphs in Figure 1.

By the definition of $\overline{\psi}_{\alpha}$, its support is $[0,1)$.

However, graphs in Figure 1 use support as $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.

Can anyone explain me about this?

Answer (score 1):

The points of $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ are mapped to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and plotted in a circle.  The plot shows
\begin{align*}
  x &= \sin (2\pi i/q), \\
  y &= \cos (2\pi i/q), \\
  p &= \Psi_\alpha(i/q).
\end{align*}
for each $i$ in the least nonnegative residues modulo $q$.

The following gnuplot script gives a similar graph, for $q = 31$:

```
set parametric
set samples 31
psi(alpha, r) = exp(-pi*(r/alpha)**2) + exp(-pi*((r - 1)/alpha)**2)
splot [i=0:30] sin(2*pi*i/31), cos(2*pi*i/31), psi(0.1, i/31) with points
```